# Extracting Page number using sentence reference from Word Document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm working to extract the page number from a word document based on specific phrases. I cannot seem to debug or understand why my code isn't working - any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated!

For a quick walkthrough, wdDoc is my current word document ... opened using GetObject(). I'm trying to print the page number to sheet1 for now just as a test case. I'm just trying to match the the first phrase (thus the "opening phrase to check" example case). And I've used a msg box to confirm that I've found an opening phrase match (i.e., the if statement is working, I just can't get the page number).

```
n = wdDoc.Sentences.Count
For i = 1 To n
If left(wdDoc.Sentences(i), 15) = Left("Opening Phrase to check"), 15) Then
   w = wdDoc.Sentences(i).Words(1)
   Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 1) = w.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the word [SET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement)

Change `w = wdDoc.Sentences(i).Words(1)` to `Set w = wdDoc.Sentences(i).Words(1)` You also have a typo in `Left("Opening Phrase to check"), 15)`. it should be `Left("Opening Phrase to check", 15)`

Try this. This works for me

```
Dim w As Object

n = wdDoc.Sentences.Count

For i = 1 To n
    If Left(wdDoc.Sentences(i), 15) = Left("Opening Phrase to check", 15) Then
        Set w = wdDoc.Sentences(i).Words(1)
        MsgBox w.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
    End If
Next i
```

**Note**: If you are late binding MS Word from MS Excel then ensure that you have declared this at the top

```
Const wdActiveEndPageNumber As Integer = 3
```